# DynamoDB - The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with attributes: userId, propertyInfo, and propertyId. userId is primary index. When I use the following lambda code to update(PUT) the item in the table, I get "The provided key element does not match the schema".

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.update = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      propertyId: event.pathParameters.id,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#new_propertyInfo': 'propertyInfo',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':propertyInfo': data.propertyInfo,
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #new_propertyInfo = :propertyInfo',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };

  dynamoDb.update(params, (error, result) => {
    // handle potential errors
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: 'Couldn\'t fetch the item.',
      });
      return;
    }

    // create a response
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Attributes),
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Body of my update request is:

```html
{
 "propertyInfo": 
 {
  "houseNumber": 2000,
  "street": "easy st"
 }
}
```

The event.pathParameters.id is obtained from /property/{id}. I need this id to search DB's propertyId. The userId is needed for authorization purpose. Search and update I need to search by propertyId. Could someone help to explain to me what I need to do to set this up correctly please?

Comment: If the partition key on your table is userId you will need to set the userId as the key in your parameters not the propertyId. If all you have is propertyId, you might need to look up the proper record, then call update with the userId key.

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink your table schema. Maybe `propertyId` should be the primary key, and `userId` would be the sort key, or maybe `userId` would be a global secondary index.

Comment: thank you guys for your inputs! I think I do need to have propertyId as GSI. Any thoughts on how to write the query using GSI rather than hash key?

Comment: You can't do that. You will have to query the table using your GSI to obtain the relevant primary key for the row you want to update.
Then do another update using the primary key as your identifier.